# efficient web scraping Python

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi I am new to web scraping and would like to scrape a website with beautifulsoop. Now I'm wondering
about how to write efficient code. This is about a bike website and they have several bikes and for each they have the features price, state, distance and duration. They all have the same class "product-feat". What is the most efficient way to get all these features into a pandas dataframe? I'm asking in particular because all features have the same class and looping seems inefficient to me.

```
<div class="product-smalltext">
<p class="product-feat">
<span>GBP 6'900 <small>(changeable)</small></span><br/> price
                </p>
<p class="product-feat">
<span>new</span><br/> state
                </p>
<p class="product-feat">
<span>10'000 km</span><br/> distance
                </p>
<p class="product-feat">
<span>48 months</span><br/> duration
                  </p>
```

I did it with a dicitionary (that I will afterwards convert to a dataframe) and a double loop, see below. But is this really
the most efficient way to do it? With loops and append/extend? Or is there a better way?

```
#empty dictionary
content={'price':[], 
         'state':[],
         'distance':[],
         'duration':[]
        }


listing_content = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"product-smalltext"})
#double loop through all bikes and features
for smalltext in listing_content:
    for feat in smalltext.find_all("p",{"class":"product-feat"}):
        content['price'].extend(re.findall(r'(?s)^.*?(?=\s*price)', feat.get_text().strip().replace('\xa0',' ')))
        content['state'].extend(re.findall(r'(?s)^.*?(?=\s*state)', feat.getText().strip()))
        content['distance'].extend(re.findall(r'(?s)^.*?(?=\s*distance)', feat.getText().strip()))
        content['duration'].extend(re.findall(r'(?s)^.*?(?=\s*duration)', feat.getText().strip()))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension and directly construct a dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame([[y.text
    for y in x.select('p.product-feat > span')]
    for x in soup.select('div[class="product-smalltext"]')],
    columns=['price', 'state', 'distance', 'duration'])
```

Output (I've added one more `<div>` to make sure it works with multiple items per page):

```
                     price state   distance   duration
0   GBP 6'900 (changeable)   new  10'000 km  48 months
1  GBP 16'900 (changeable)   old  20'000 km  48 months
```

---

**Update:** We can also extract names of the product features from the text and use it as column names. If some values are missing, we'll get `NaN`s in the dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame([{y.find('br').next_sibling.strip(): y.find('span').text
    for y in x.select('p.product-feat')}
    for x in soup.select('div[class="product-smalltext"]')])
```

---

**Update 2:** With the specific website:

```
resp = requests.get('https://www.leasingmarkt.ch/listing')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(resp.text)

df = pd.DataFrame([{y.find('br').next_sibling.strip(): y.find('span').text
    for y in x.select('p.product-feat')}
    for x in soup.select('div[class="product-smalltext"]')])

df
```

Output:

```
                Anzahlung Erstzulassung Jährliche Fahrleistung  \
0       CHF 0 (anpassbar)      Neuwagen  10'000 km (anpassbar)   
1  CHF 13'250 (anpassbar)      Neuwagen  10'000 km (anpassbar)   
2   CHF 2'000 (anpassbar)      Neuwagen              10'000 km   
3  CHF 10'000 (anpassbar)      Neuwagen  15'000 km (anpassbar)   
4   CHF 1'500 (anpassbar)      Neuwagen              10'000 km   
5   CHF 3'500 (anpassbar)      Neuwagen              10'000 km   
6   CHF 6'900 (anpassbar)      Neuwagen              10'000 km   
7  CHF 10'500 (anpassbar)      Neuwagen  10'000 km (anpassbar)   
8       CHF 0 (anpassbar)       08/2015              10'000 km   
9       CHF 0 (anpassbar)      Neuwagen  10'000 km (anpassbar)   

                Laufzeit Kilometerstand                  Leistung  
0  48 Monate (anpassbar)           0 km  204 PS (150 kW), Elektro  
1  48 Monate (anpassbar)           0 km   245 PS (180 kW), Benzin  
2              48 Monate           0 km   190 PS (140 kW), Benzin  
3  48 Monate (anpassbar)           0 km   150 PS (110 kW), Benzin  
4              48 Monate           0 km  204 PS (150 kW), Elektro  
5              48 Monate           0 km   320 PS (235 kW), Benzin  
6              48 Monate           0 km    129 PS (95 kW), Benzin  
7  48 Monate (anpassbar)           0 km   184 PS (135 kW), Benzin  
8              48 Monate      46'000 km   190 PS (140 kW), Diesel  
9  48 Monate (anpassbar)           0 km   320 PS (235 kW), Benzin
```

---

**Update 3:** And here's with `selenium`:

```
url = 'https://www.leasingmarkt.ch/listing'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

html = driver.page_source
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)

df = pd.DataFrame([{y.find('br').next_sibling.strip(): y.find('span').text
    for y in x.select('p.product-feat')}
    for x in soup.select('div[class="product-smalltext"]')])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just realised, what do you do if for some rows there is an empty state? How can you make that a nan in the dataframe and how can you avoid that all values get shifted to the left?

Comment: That's great, thanks. The only thing left is that this doesn't work because there is also class 'product-smalltext listing' so soup.select('div.product-smalltext')]) will give both product-smalltext listing and product-smalltext and only product-smalltext has product-feat. This worked with the loop solution, but how would you do it here?

Comment: Cool, so you want to specify it to have only the "product-smalltext" class. You can do it with `...for x in soup.select('div[class="product-smalltext"]')]...`, please see the updated Update

Comment: somehow it still chooses the class `product-smalltext listing` as well and not just `product-smalltext` and I get the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`

Comment: Can you share the HTML or a link to the website please?

Comment: Hm, seems to work for me, see 'Update 2'. Or did I miss something?

Comment: i used the `soup = BeautifulSoup(html)` and then it really doesn't work. If I define soup the way you did, so `soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text)`, it does work. Do you know why?

Comment: Shouldn't matter as long as your `html` is the string with HTML source of the page. The problem is likely with the way you get the `html` variable. You can try to print it and see if it shows the source correctly

Comment: I did this `driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)`. How do I know what it prints is correct, its just very long html

Comment: Do you need to use `selenium` for some reason? If not, just use `requests`. It is a better option if all you need is to get the source of the page

Comment: Yes, need selenium as part of the html is javascript

Comment: Added Update 3 with `selenium` (works fine for me, same output as in Update 2)

Comment: I'm sorry, there is one more thing with the list comprehension I wanted to ask. Sometimes there is a '\n' after the `span` so that next_sibling will only give '\n' and what I'm actually looking for is next_sibling.next_sibling. Is there a way to remove the '\n' (without transforming to string) and then apply next_sibling to that?

Comment: @corianne1234 Maybe just remove `\n`s in the string when you pass it to BeautifulSoup?

Comment: something like this `BeautifulSoup(html.content.replace('\n',''), 'lxml')`?

Comment: @corianne1234 Yes, exactly. Did it help?

Comment: no, unfortunately it gives me an error `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Comment: In the selenium option (Update 3), I can change `bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)` to `bs4.BeautifulSoup(html.replace('\n', ''))`. If that doesn't work for you, please post the specific code that you're using as well as the HTML/URL of the website

Comment: yes, that works but it replaces '\n' with ' ' instead of ''.

Comment: In my example it doesn't. I can have a look at why it fails in your case, but I can't help without seeing your code and data